# Issue sniffing PCAP

Tags: c, ethernet, pcap

I don't understand why my following code doesn't work properly.
When I sniff ethernet the bytes that I receive are shifted by 2 bytes

I send use `sudo sendip -p ipv4 -p udp 127.0.0.1 -d r8` to send packet to my computer

With the following code:

```
#include <pcap/pcap.h>

#define SIZE_ETHERNET 14
#define ETHER_ADDR_LEN  6
struct sniff_ethernet {
        u_char  ether_dhost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];
        u_char  ether_shost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];
        u_short ether_type;
};


void packet_call_back(u_char *user, const struct pcap_pkthdr *h, const u_char *bytes) { 
    struct sniff_ethernet *ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(bytes);
    printf("test = %#x\n", ethernet->ether_type); // print is 0x0
}

int     main(void) {
    char    errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    pcap_t  *handle = pcap_create("any", errbuf);
    pcap_set_timeout(handle, -1);
    pcap_loop(handle, 0, packet_call_back, NULL);
    pcap_close(handle);
}
```

The ether_type that I receive is incorrect here `0x0000` instead of `0x0800`

but if instead of: `struct sniff_ethernet *ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(bytes);`
I put `struct sniff_ethernet *ethernet = (struct sniff_ethernet*)(bytes + 2);`
here everything work fine and I can analyse my packet easily.

I compile with `gcc test.c -l pcap`
And I work on an Ubuntu VM with parallels

Thank's for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I sniff ethernet the bytes that I receive are shifted by 2 bytes

You're not sniffing Ethernet, you're sniffing the "any" device.  That will capture on all interfaces, whether they're Ethernet interfaces or not; even if they are all Ethernet interfaces, that doesn't make a difference.

In order to make this work, a link-layer header type *other* than Ethernet is used on the "any" device.  On Linux, that's a special header; [here's what that header looks like](https://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes/LINKTYPE_LINUX_SLL.html).

*ALL* programs that use libpcap to capture network traffic *or* to read a capture file *must*, after opening the capture device (`pcap_activate()`, `pcap_open_live()`, `pcap_open()`) or the capture file (`pcap_open_offline()`), call `pcap_datalink()` to determine the link-layer header type from the device or the file.

That function returns a value that can be found in [the link-layer header types list](https://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html); it will be one of the values with a name that begins with `DLT_`.  Do *not* check for the numerical values given there; check for the `DLT_` values.